# Angular 2 - Pipesorting - Correct Syntax

Tags: angular, pipe, syntax-error

I want to create a pipe for angular 2 im using it correctly in my html but everytime it is used array.sort is read as a property or so. The error is Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined and here is the code of my pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform  } from "@angular/core";

import { Player } from './player';

@Pipe({
  name: "arraysorting",
  pure:false,
})
export class LeaderboardSortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: Array<Player>, args: string): Array<Player> {
    array.sort((a: Player, b: Player) => {
      if (a[args] < b[args]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[args] > b[args]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

Edit:
Here is my HTML code for this

```
<ul *ngIf="type!='' && amount==0" class="leaderboard">
    <li *ngFor="let player of players  | sort | slice:0; let i=index">
        <span class="badge">{{player.id}}</span>{{player.name}}
        <span *ngIf="type=='ratio'" class="points">{{player[type].toFixed(2)}} %</span>
        <span *ngIf="type!='ratio'" class="points">{{player[type]}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The sort order is not important right now the problem is, that it isnt sorting at all in any direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ensure that the pipe doesn't throw when `null` is passed as value

```
transform(array: Array<Player>, args: string): Array<Player> {
    if(!array) {
      return null;
    }
    array.sort((a: Player, b: Player) => {
```

Comment: Of course it is. Otherwise you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable. How do you want to have them sorted?